# Debugging PHP's segmentation fault

Tags: php, c, linux

I have a problem with PHP5.4.11 and APC extension (on apache2). After certain amount of cached files it crashes. I'm guessing I need a core dump to investigate it with gdb? I also assume I have to compile the extension (or perhaps) the whole PHP with a debug flag to make the source code visible to gdb?

The above is my good guess. If there is a better approach I'm open for suggestions.

Comment: Do you have a code example that will reliably cause a crash? What OS/version are you on? Have you any more detail than 'segmentation fault' from your OS logs? I wonder if turning up PHP's or Apache's loglevel might help also?

Comment: Did you compile PHP + APC yourself on the system you are using it on? Or are you using a pre-compiled version?

Comment: I compiled both PHP and APC. I use it on linux (debian). I'm aware that APC is not consider stable for PHP 5.4 yet. Apache log says as always in those cases "seg fault". Crash is consistent after certain amount of data on "heavy" pages.

Comment: It's probably a bug in this release. Can't you use [5.3.21 stable](http://php.net/downloads.php) instead? (while waiting for a fix in 5.4.11)

Comment: it's a bug and I want to find it and fix it. No I can't got with PHP below 5.4 as it doesn't support Traits.

Comment: [APC](http://pecl.php.net/package/APC) is an independent module (it doesn't come with the PHP *tar* file), and the last version is Sept 2012. Thus is seems the problem may come directly from PHP - which is harder to find. I had a APC issue while updating files via `rsync`, just in case it rings a bell...

Comment: ring0: this is valid point. Funny thing is that when I compiled PHP and APC with debug symbols and set system to dump cores APC stopped crashing... it's little bit like quantum physics

Answer (score 0):

try to add an segfault handler in the C code you compile this will help you finding where is the problem

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <execinfo.h>
#include <signal.h>

void *array[50];
char **strings;
size_t size,i;

void handler(int)
{
size = backtrace(array,50);
strings = backtrace_symbols(array,size);
for (i=0;i < size;i++)
   printf("%s\n",strings[i]);
free(strings);
printf("sig sev caught\n");
exit(0);
}

void toto()
{
char *x;
*x = 8; // writing uninitialized pointer
}

int main()
{
signal(SIGSEGV,handler);

toto();

}
```